# Save and open excel file in java

Tags: java

I want to export data on a 'Jtable' to excel file and when the export is successful a massage dialog box is displayed and the user can ether choose to open the saved file or not. I have already figured out how to save the file. But I'm not sure how to open the file I just saved. In order to do that I believe these two lines need to be fixed.

```
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.open(new File(this.file));
```

Below is my coding so far.

```
private void ExportbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    try{
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        int option = fc.showSaveDialog(SearchGUI.this);
        if(option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            try{
                String filename = fc.getSelectedFile().getName(); 
                String path = fc.getSelectedFile().getParentFile().getPath();

                int len = filename.length();
                String ext = "";
                String file = "";

                if(len > 4){
        ext = filename.substring(len-4, len);
                }

                if(ext.equals(".xls")){
        file = path + "\\" + filename; 
                }else{
        file = path + "\\" + filename + ".xls"; 
                }
                toExcel(PhoneBook, new File(file));
                int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to open the exported file?", "Successfully exported!", option);
                if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
                        dt.open(new File(this.file));

                    } catch (Exception e ){
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    }
                }

                }catch(Exception e){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

please help!!

Comment: Use apache POI to manipulate excel files!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

caught the error it should be

```
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.open(new File(file));
```

Instead of

```
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.open(new File(this.file));
```